# Access another class variable through functon in c++

Tags: c++, class, variables

I am trying to change the value of a variable of class A, throughh a function that is defined/declared in class B. I tried more than one ways and i did not find one that is working.

```
File : myheader.h

class A {
public:
int x;
};


class B:public A
{
public:
void Print(void)
  {
    A::x=0;
  }
};
```

ok, and in main ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myheader.h"

using namespace std;

A mya;
B myb;

int main(){
mya.x=10;
cout<<mya.x<<endl; //That will print 10
myb.Print();
cout<<mya.x<<endl; //That will print also 10, i want it to print 0
return 0;
}
```

That prints 10 and 10. I want to have access to variable x in class A through a function from class B. I can't find somethind that works...

Comment: mya is an object with x let's call it x1, myb is another object with x let's call it x2 when you call `mya.x = 10` it means `x1 = 10` when you call `myb.print()` it means x2 = 0, when you call `cout << mya.x << endl;` this means print x1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `mya` and `myb` are separate instances.  Two entirely different objects.

`myb.Print()` changes the value of `x` on the `myb` object (`myb.x`), but does nothing whatsoever to `mya`.  Try printing `myb.x` with your last `cout` line:

```
cout << myb.x << endl;
```

------ EDIT (in response to your comment) ------

Consider the following code.

The way to have an instance of `B` (in this case `Cat`) operate on an instance of `A` (in this case `Animal`) is to pass a reference to an instance of A to an instance of B (`tom.eats( jerry );`).

In this example, the instances are `tom`, `jerry`, and `spike`.  Similar to your `mya` and `myb`.

```
class Animal {

public:

    Animal() { _alive = true; }

    bool isAlive() { return _alive; }                   // getter
    void setAlive( bool value ) { _alive = value; }     // setter

    bool _alive;

};

class Cat : public Animal {

public:

    void eats( Animal &animal ) {
        animal.setAlive( false );
    }

};

class Mouse : public Animal { };


int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    Cat             tom;
    Mouse           jerry;
    Animal          spike;              // a dog, but could be any animal

    cout << tom.isAlive() << endl;      // true, the cat named "tom" is alive
    cout << jerry.isAlive() << endl;    // true, the mouse named "jerry" is alive
    cout << spike.isAlive() << endl;    // true, the dog named "spike" is alive

    tom.eats( jerry );                  // the cat eats the mouse.  so sad.
                                        // the cat can do this because Mouse is also an Animal

    cout << tom.isAlive() << endl;      // true, the cat named "tom" is alive
    cout << jerry.isAlive() << endl;    // false, the mouse named "jerry" is not alive
    cout << spike.isAlive() << endl;    // true, the dog named "spike" is alive

    tom.eats( spike );                  // the cat eats the dog. impressive.
                                        // the cat can do this because spike is an Animal

    cout << tom.isAlive() << endl;      // true, the cat named "tom" is alive
    cout << jerry.isAlive() << endl;    // false, the mouse named "jerry" is not alive
    cout << spike.isAlive() << endl;    // false, the dog named "spike" is not alive

    tom.eats( tom );                    // the cat eats itself.  this cat is really hungry. 
                                        // the cat can do this because Cat is an Animal

    cout << tom.isAlive() << endl;      // false, the cat named "tom" is not alive
    cout << jerry.isAlive() << endl;    // false, the mouse named "jerry" is not alive
    cout << spike.isAlive() << endl;    // false, the dog named "spike" is not alive

    spike.eats( tom );                  // error, Animal class has no eats() method so
                                        // this won't compile
}
```

Comment: Yes, i see that, my purpose is to have a function in class B that when i make an object of classs B (for example myb) i can call the function and have access to variable x that will be in object mya, of class A. How can i do that ??

Comment: hahaha nice example.. i get it man thanks a lot, you made me laugh and you answered my question!! thanks again ..

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please accept the answer if you're happy with it.